convert row data in column wise in html table in javascript array of object
below i have an array of object  in javascript
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 12951
        [user_id] => 1
        [balance_amt] => 100
        [year] => 2020
        [username] => User1
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 11751
        [user_id] => 2
        [balance_amt] => 100
        [year] => 2020
        [username] => User2
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 12816
        [user_id] => 1
        [balance_amt] => 100
        [year] => 2021
        [username] => User1
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 11014
        [user_id] => 3
        [balance_amt] => 0
        [year] => 2020
        [username] => User3
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 11817
        [user_id] => 2
        [balance_amt] => 100
        [year] => 2021
        [username] => User2
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 12466
        [user_id] => 3
        [balance_amt] => 100
        [year] => 2021
        [username] => User3
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 10664
        [user_id] => 3
        [balance_amt] => 0
        [year] => 2022
        [username] =>User3
    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 8944
        [user_id] => 3
        [balance_amt] => 100
        [year] => 2023
        [username] => User3
    )

[8] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 7269
        [user_id] => 1
        [balance_amt] => 0
        [year] => 2022
        [username] => User1
    )

[9] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 5632
        [user_id] => 2
        [balance_amt] => 0
        [year] => 2022
        [username] => User2
    )

[10] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 4034
        [user_id] => 3
        [balance_amt] => 0
        [year] => 2024
        [username] => User3
    )

[11] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2476
        [user_id] => 2
        [balance_amt] => 0
        [year] => 2023
        [username] => User2
    )

using above data i am displaying records in table like below



Username
year
Balance




User1
2020
100


User1
2021
100


User1
2022
0


User2
2020
100


User2
2021
100


User2
2022
0


User2
2023
0


User3
2020
0


User3
2021
100


User3
2022
0


User3
2023
100


User3
2024
0



but i want to display the result like below table



Username
2020
2021
2022
2023
2024




User1
100
100
0
-
-


User2
100
100
0
0
-


User3
0
100
0
100
0



i tried the code but i am not getting the result. so I would appreciate any help with this!
response.reduce((a2, c2) => { let filteredP = a2.filter(el => el.year === c2.year) if (filteredP.length > 0) { a2[a2.indexOf(filteredP[0])].balance_amt += +c2.balance_amt; } else { a2.push(c2); } return a2; }, []);

What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Additionally, please see: Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?  And: Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?

my code
yearly_response.reduce((a2, c2) => {
let filteredP = a2.filter(el => el.year === c2.year)
if (filteredP.length > 0) {
a2[a2.indexOf(filteredP[0])].balance_amt += +c2.balance_amt;
} else {
a2.push(c2);
}
return a2;
}, []);

Please update the question to include a [mcve], ideally as a runnable code snippet, which demonstrates the problem you have encountered in your attempt and what you are asking about that specific problem.

What's driving the "below table"? What are the rules for how it's displaying?

I am displaying that javascript array into html table (first table) but i want to display it like second table

Yes, but what's the logic behind the second table? What are the rules? What if your data is different? Should it still show exactly like the second image?

Second table reduces my row and i can easily find out the balance amount according to year of particular user this are only minimal data i have large data so i am trying to get result like second table

Maybe a better question is *How is the table generated from the array? * We have no idea what kind of data format is needed to generate the table as desired. We've been discussing JS algorithms, but none of the code provided has anything to do with the html generated.

The way I would tackle the problem, is to build a list of Users and a list of Years from your data. Then create the table you want from those new lists.
One example below.
Note: You probably want to put the years in an array and sort them, since the properties of an object can be in any order. I'll leave that as an exercise for you.


let Users = {}  // {name:{year:amount}, name:{year:amount}, ... }
let Years = {}  // {year:true, year:true, ...}  //
let UserData = [
  { id: 12951, user_id: 1, balance_amt: 100, year: 2020, username: "User1" },
  { id: 11751, user_id: 2, balance_amt: 456, year: 2023, username: "User2" }
]


function doTest( ) {
  buildUsersAndYears( )
  createTable( )
}


function buildUsersAndYears( ) {
  // Build lists of Users and Years from the data
  for( let user of UserData ) {
    if( !Users[user.username] ) Users[user.username] = {}
    Users[user.username][user.year] = user.balance_amt

    Years[user.year] = true // Could be anything, just need a property
  }
}


function createTable( ) {
  let table = document.createElement( "table" )
  let tableHtml = ""


  tableHtml = "<thead><tr> <th>Username</th> "
  for( let year in Years ) {
    tableHtml += `<th>${year}</th>`
  }
  tableHtml += "</tr></thead>"

  tableHtml += "<tbody>"
  for( let user in Users ) {
    tableHtml += `<tr> <td>${user}</td>`
    for( let year in Years ) {
      tableHtml += `<td>${Users[user][year]!=undefined ? Users[user][year] : ""}</td>`
    }
    tableHtml += `</tr>`
  }
  tableHtml += "</tbody>"

  table.innerHTML = tableHtml
  document.querySelector( "#TestAreaID" ).appendChild( table )  // Finaly add the table to the DOM
}
<div id="TestAreaID">
</div>




Your code is good and does summarize the data per your desires. The only challenge is that the balance_amt which should be numeric is presented to your code as a string.
If you fix your data at the source to return a numeric amount, your code should work.
As you can see in the demo below, the only change I made was to convert the initial amount value to numeric.
Also remember that not every user will have an entry for every year other users have an entry; read the absence as a zero balance (or just -).


const users = [{ id: "12951", user_id: "1", balance_amt: "100", year: "2020", username: "User1" },{ id: "11751", user_id: "2", balance_amt: "100", year: "2020", username: "User2" },{ id: "12816", user_id: "1", balance_amt: "100", year: "2021", username: "User1" },{ id: "11014", user_id: "3", balance_amt: "0", year: "2020", username: "User3" },{ id: "11817", user_id: "2", balance_amt: "100", year: "2021", username: "User2" },{ id: "12466", user_id: "3", balance_amt: "100", year: "2021", username: "User3" },{ id: "10664", user_id: "3", balance_amt: "0", year: "2022", username: "User3" },{ id: "8944", user_id: "3", balance_amt: "100", year: "2023", username: "User3" },{ id: "7269", user_id: "1", balance_amt: "0", year: "2022", username: "User1" },{ id: "5632", user_id: "2", balance_amt: "0", year: "2022", username: "User2" },{ id: "4034", user_id: "3", balance_amt: "0", year: "2024", username: "User3" },{ id: "2476", user_id: "2", balance_amt: "0", year: "2023", username: "User2" }];

const output = users.reduce((a2, c2) => { 
    let filteredP = a2.filter(el => el.year === c2.year); 
    if (filteredP.length > 0) { 
        a2[a2.indexOf(filteredP[0])].balance_amt = +a2[a2.indexOf(filteredP[0])].balance_amt;
        a2[a2.indexOf(filteredP[0])].balance_amt += +c2.balance_amt; 
    } else {
        c2.balance_amt = +c2.balance_amt;
        a2.push(c2); 
    } 
    return a2; 
}, []);

console.log( output );




The conversion of your data into a tabular form can be done in two steps:

create an object (uobj) into which you accumulate the balance_amt for each user and year
get all the (sorted by name) entries from that uobj and turn them into a table, using yearsArr as headers for the columns



const data = [ /* inserted object: */{ id: "11953", user_id: "3", balance_amt: "50", year: "2021", username: "User3" },
              { id: "12951", user_id: "1", balance_amt: "100", year: "2020", username: "User1" },{ id: "11751", user_id: "2", balance_amt: "100", year: "2020", username: "User2" },{ id: "12816", user_id: "1", balance_amt: "100", year: "2021", username: "User1" },{ id: "11014", user_id: "3", balance_amt: "0", year: "2020", username: "User3" },{ id: "11817", user_id: "2", balance_amt: "100", year: "2021", username: "User2" },{ id: "12466", user_id: "3", balance_amt: "100", year: "2021", username: "User3" },{ id: "10664", user_id: "3", balance_amt: "0", year: "2022", username: "User3" },{ id: "8944", user_id: "3", balance_amt: "100", year: "2023", username: "User3" },{ id: "7269", user_id: "1", balance_amt: "0", year: "2022", username: "User1" },{ id: "5632", user_id: "2", balance_amt: "0", year: "2022", username: "User2" },{ id: "4034", user_id: "3", balance_amt: "0", year: "2024", username: "User3" },{ id: "2476", user_id: "2", balance_amt: "0", year: "2023", username: "User2" }];
const years=new Set();
const uobj = data.reduce((a,c)=>{
  const u=(a[c.username]??={});
  years.add(c.year); 
  u[c.year]=(u[c.year]??0)+ +c.balance_amt;
  return a;
}, {});
const yearsArr=[...years].sort();
console.log("unsorted output of accumulated balance_amt in uobj:",uobj);

const table=[["Username",...yearsArr],
...Object.entries(uobj).sort(([a],[b])=>a.localeCompare(b))
  .map(([u,o])=>[u,...yearsArr.map(y=>o[y]??"")])];
console.log("sorted tabular output:",table);



(In order to properly test my algorithm I inserted a further user object at the beginning  of the input array data.)
